# SOAP Web services: object aliasing in response?

Tags: web-services, soap, marshalling

If a web service returns an object graph where some objects appear multiple times, will the data about these objects necessarily be duplicated in the transport format?

Put differently: With Java serialization, each object's state is written only once, and subsequent references to that object are mere pointers within the serialization stream. Is there a (preferable portable, i.e. WI-Basic-Profile compliant) way to achieve the same when (un)marshalling a webservice request or response?

Example: Given the classes

```
class Project {
    Task[] tasks;
}

class Task {
    User assignee;
}

class User {
    // some data
}
```

The webservice is supposed to return a `Project`, and I'd like to send each `User` at most once, regardless of how many tasks he is assigned in the project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that SOAP can serialize object graphs by using `encodingStyle`, but using `encodingStyle` contradicts WS-I Basic Profile 1.1. [(source)](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/ws-tip-j2eenet1/index.html#N100C7)